# Export to PEM format using CryptoAPI

Tags: c++, c, ssl, cryptoapi

I have a certificate from the windows store and I would like to extract the public key in PEM format using the CryptoAPI.

```
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCert = CertFindCertificateInStore (...);
```

From the `pCert` there is no obvious way to get the public key certificate in PEM format using CryptoAPI.

Answer (score 0):

[`CertFindCertificateInStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns [`PCCERT_CONTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has a `pCertInfo` as a member, of type [`PCERT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which on its turn has a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` member of type [`CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which supposedly has what you need ) ... hope this helps :)

Comment: I need to have it as a PEM format. I am not sure to really know into which format the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` is.

Comment: @mathk Did you get a solution?